# I want my program to not count same numbers again

Tags: python, data-structures, line

*Here is my code:*

```
from random import randint
total = int(input('Enter the number of iterations'))  
count=0
for i in range(1,total+1):
    print('i',i)
    number1=randint(1,5)
    print('num1',number1)
    number2=randint(1,5)
    print('num2',number2)
    if number1==number2:
        count+=1
print('The number matched',count)
```

*Here is the code result:*

```
Enter the number of iterations
>>> 20
i 1
num1 2
num2 1
i 2
num1 5
num2 3
i 3
num1 5
num2 5
i 4
num1 4
num2 5
i 5
num1 1
num2 1
i 6
num1 5
num2 5
i 7
num1 4
num2 1
i 8
num1 5
num2 5
i 9
num1 4
num2 5
i 10
num1 3
num2 3
i 11
num1 5
num2 5
i 12
num1 1
num2 5
i 13
num1 1
num2 5
i 14
num1 2
num2 4
i 15
num1 1
num2 1
i 16
num1 1
num2 5
i 17
num1 3
num2 4
i 18
num1 2
num2 5
i 19
num1 2
num2 5
i 20
num1 1
num2 4
The number matched 7
```

I write a program that generates two numbers in the range 1 to 5 inclusive and outputs the string 'The numbers matched' if the numbers match. I want the program to not count the same numbers. For example in my program I want the result:

```
The number matched 3
5 5 ; 1 1 ; 3 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect the numbers that matched in a **set**. That way they will not be added more than once. At the end you can check the size of that set:

```
from random import randint

total = int(input('Enter the number of iterations: '))  
duplicates = set()
for i in range(total):
    number1 = randint(1, 5)
    number2 = randint(1, 5)
    if number1 == number2:
        duplicates.add(number1)

print('The number of matches:', len(duplicates))
print('These numbers occurred in pairs:', sorted(duplicates))
```

A run could for instance output:

```
Enter the number of iterations: 20
The number of matches: 3
These numbers occurred in pairs: [1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
total = int(input('Enter the number of iterations'))  
count=0
my_dict = {}
for i in range(1,6):
    my_dict[i] = 0
for i in range(1,total+1):
    print('i',i)
    number1=randint(1,5)
    print('num1',number1)
    number2=randint(1,5)
    print('num2',number2)
    if number1==number2:
        my_dict[number1] = my_dict[number1] + 1 
print('The number matched',my_dict)
```

In this way the output is a dictionary in which the keys are the numbers from 1 to 5 and the values are the number of times that number match with the same number.

For e.g. for 20 iterations:

Output:

```
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
```